# Patching an already-installed package?

Tags: apt, patch

Is it possible to apply a [.patch file](https://developer.pidgin.im/raw-attachment/ticket/1540/pidgin-2.0.1-pounceall.patch) to a package that's already installed? If not, and the package was installed via apt, does that mean one would have to

1. Uninstall/purge the package from apt
2. Download the package source files
3. Apply the patch to the source files
4. Install the patched-package from source
5. Redo steps 2-4 above each time they wanted to upgrade a package

?

I.E., there's no way to use patch files and apt together? I've installed from source before but I'd like to continue using apt to install/update if at all possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in assuming that patches need to be applied to source code, not the compiled package that's installed on the system. This is because the `.patch` file contains information about differences in source code files. The compiled version of the program is in binary form and is unchangeable.

Keep in mind that `apt` has a handy tool for autobuilding packages from source, `apt-source`.

Answer (score 0):

If the Application is already installed, try with:

```
sudo patch `<application name>` <DirectoryOfPatchFile>/<filename>.patch
```